# Teradata - Split date range into month columns with day count

Tags: sql, teradata

I need to split different date ranges over a quarter period into month columns with only the days actually used in that month. Each record (range) would be different.

**Example**:

**Table**

```
Record_ID Start_Date  End_Date
1         10/27       11/30
2         11/30       12/14
3         12/14       12/31

Range 1 = 10/5 to 12/14
Range 2 = 11/20 to 12/31
Range 3 = 10/28 to 12/2
```

**Output**:

**Range 1**

```
Oct    Nov    Dec 
27     30     14
```

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: It just has: Record_ID, Start_Date, End_Date

Comment: Does the period of time between start and end ever cross over to the next year (if so, how would that be displayed). Does the period of time between start and end ever cover more than 1 year (again how would that be displayed here)?

Comment: Your ranges all overlap, and I have no idea what your output represents. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to @ULick's answer using sys_calendar.calendar, but a little more succinct:

```
CREATE VOLATILE MULTISET TABLE datetest (record_id int, start_date date, end_date date) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO datetest VALUES (1, '2017-10-05', '2017-12-14');
INSERT INTO datetest VALUES (2, '2017-11-20','2017-12-31');

SELECT record_id, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_of_year = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as October,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_of_year = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as November,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_of_year = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as December
FROM datetest
    INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar cal 
        ON cal.calendar_date BETWEEN start_date and end_date
GROUP BY record_id;

DROP TABLE datetest;
```

Because Quarter was mentioned in the question (I'm not sure how it relates here) there is also `quarter_of_year` and `month_of_quarter` available in the sys_calendar to slice and dice this even further.

Also, if you are on 16.00+ There is PIVOT functionality which may help get rid of the CASE statements here.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. Exactly what I needed, I just couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

First join with the calendar to get all the dates within the range and get the number of days per each month (incl. full month, not mentioned in Start_Date and End_Date).

Then sum up each month in a column per Range.

```
create table SplitDateRange ( Range bigint, Start_Date date,  End_Date date );
insert into SplitDateRange values ( 1, '2018-10-05', '2018-12-14' );
insert into SplitDateRange values ( 2, '2018-11-20', '2018-12-31' );
insert into SplitDateRange values ( 3, '2018-10-28', '2018-12-02' );

select
          Range
        , sum(case when mon = 10 then days else 0 end) as "Oct"
        , sum(case when mon = 11 then days else 0 end) as "Nov"
        , sum(case when mon = 12 then days else 0 end) as "Dec"
from (
        select
                Range
                , extract(MONTH from C.calendar_date) as mon
                , max(C.calendar_date) - min(calendar_date) +1 as days
        from Sys_Calendar.CALENDAR as C
        inner join SplitDateRange as DR
        on C.calendar_date between DR.Start_Date and DR.End_Date
        group by 1,2
) A
group by Range
order by Range
;
```

Comment: After the edit, I don't understand, how the first (added)  table is related to the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Different approach, avoids the cross join to the calendar by applying Teradata *Expand On* feature for creating time series. More text, but should be more efficient for larger tables/ranges:

```
SELECT record_id,
   Sum(CASE WHEN mth = 10 THEN days_in_month ELSE 0 END) AS October,
   Sum(CASE WHEN mth = 11 THEN days_in_month ELSE 0 END) AS November,
   Sum(CASE WHEN mth = 12 THEN days_in_month ELSE 0 END) AS December
FROM 
 ( -- this Derived Table simply avoids repeating then EXTRACT/INTERVAL calculations (can't be done directly in the nested Select)
   SELECT record_id,
      Extract(MONTH From Begin(expanded_pd)) AS mth, 
      Cast((INTERVAL( base_pd P_INTERSECT expanded_pd) DAY) AS INT) AS days_in_month
   FROM 
    (
      SELECT record_id,
         PERIOD(start_date, end_date+1) AS base_pd, 
         expanded_pd
      FROM datetest
        -- creates one row per month
      EXPAND ON base_pd AS expanded_pd BY ANCHOR PERIOD Month_Begin
    ) AS dt
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Thanks dnoeth! I really appreciate it.